# Ninject Contextual Binding w/ Open Generics

Tags: c#, generics, repository, dynamics-crm-2011, ninject

I have a generic interface `IRepository<T>` and two implementations `xrmRepository<T>` and `efRepository<T>`

I want to change the binding based on `T`, more specifically use `xrmRepository` when `T` derives from `Entity`. How can I accomplish that?

I currently have:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(efRepository<>)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(xrmRepository<>)).When(request => request.Service.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity))).InRequestScope();
```

But when I try to resolve `IRepository<Contact>` it goes to efRepository, even though  Contact inherits Entity.

I don't want to use Named Bindings otherwise I will have to add the names everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also define the bindings like this. I don't know about run time performance, but I think it's more readable this way. And if I'm not missing something it should result in the same behavior.

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
      .To(typeof(efRepository<>))
      .InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind<IRepository<Entity>>()
      .To<xrmRepository<Entity>>()
      .InRequestScope();
```

**Edit**

If the goal is to use xrmRepository for every class inheriting from Entity this should do the trick

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
                    .To(typeof(XrmRepository<>))
                    .When(request => typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(request.Service.GetGenericArguments()[0]));
```

Comment: Didn't work using the base class "Entity". Still binding to efRepository. Does work if use the class itself (like Contact).

Comment: Do you want to resolve IRepository to xrmRepository for all subclasses of Entity?

Comment: Yep! But I will probably end up creating an IXRMRepository : IRepository instead since I can't get it to work.

Comment: Yes, it should work for all types that can be assigned to Entity

Answer (score 2):

Use `When` method to declare a binding condition. Example is given below

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
      .To(typeof(efRepository<>))
      .When(request => request.Service.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(Entity))
      .InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
      .To(typeof(xrmRepository<>))
      .InRequestScope();

kernel.Get<IRepository<Entity>>(); //will return efRepository<Entity>

kernel.Get<IRepository<int>>(); //will return xrmRepository<int>
```

Comment: Keep getting the error "GenericArguments[0], 'sf2015.Infrastructure.Xrm.Contact', on 'sf2015.Repositories.sfRepository`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.". Aditional info: f2015.Infrastructure.Xrm.Contact is of type Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity. I had to change First() to [0] and the xrmRepository is the one supposed to bind with Entity. See updated question.

Comment: @JoaoLeme give interface definitions and their implementation. Also give examples of calling **Get** and expected results

Comment: When calling Get from a new Module it works if I use ...GetGenericArguments().First() == typeof(Contact)... and call kernel.Get<IRepository<Contact>>(); but if I replace Contact on the binding by its inherited class Entity and call kernel.Get<IRepository<Contact>>() I get the same error. By the way, doing the same troubleshoot trick (replacing Entity by Contact) under RegisterServices in NinjectWebCommon doesn't work (Eitherway gives me the same error).